# uvicorn not closing correctly

Tags: python, windows, fastapi, uvicorn

I start uvicorn from the command prompt using the command
`uvicorn app:api --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000`,
then closing using the CTRL+C command, the server shuts down correctly. However, if I add `--workers 2` to the command, the child processes are closed, but the main process is not, preventing access to the console. What could be the issue?